# Finding a pleasant-natured expression for a list of things you want to learn

Tags: meaning, word-request, phrase-request

Imagine you write down a list of things you want to learn.  For example:

- speaking Spanish
- playing piano
- cooking sushi, etc.

What name you would give such a list? 
German has a single word for it, which is "*Lernwunsch*".

Directly translated into English it would be "learn wish", but this expression doesn`t exist. Is there a pleasant-natured expression?  (*Curriculum*, *syllabus*, and *prerequisites* sound too academic.)

Comment: Details, [please](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please)

Comment: The three phrases you're asking about aren't grammatically correct in English, so we need more detail to understand what you're asking. Explain a little more why you are interested in the differences.

Comment: Thanks ColleenV. Imaging you write down a list of all things / skills you want to learn. How you would such a list call?

Comment: Hi Felix, welcome to ELL. Please use the "edit" facility to change your question text, rather than adding extra details in comments.

Comment: Felix, I've improved your edit (we don't include salutations or signatures on StackExchange), but the best answer that I could give is that such a single word probably doesn't exist, though I'm happy to be proven wrong; it's also an interesting concept, so if there's a phrase we'd use to express this, I'd also be keen to know. German employs language differently though, so even though it's graphologically a single word and one noun, it probably isn't.

Comment: An expression is not usually thought of as being *pleasant-natured* or not. People are *pleasant-natured*. Maybe you mean *pleasant* or *pleasant-sounding*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean:

- "Request to learn"?  When you ask someone to teach you something, you are making a request to learn that thing.
- "Wish to learn"?  A "wish" is something in your own thoughts.  If you "wish to learn" something, you hope that you will understand that thing, and be able to use your understanding.
- "Desire to learn"?  A "desire to learn" is basically the same idea as a "wish to learn".

"A list of skills you want to learn" is pleasant and straight-forward.

A "bucket list" is an informal term that has become popular in the last few years.  People use it as a "list of things they want to do before they die".  It often includes things they want to learn.  The song "[Live Like You Were Dying](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxDkWBvxHEI)" and the movie *[The Bucket List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bucket_List)* popularized the idea.

Comment: thanks, Jasper. Imaging you make a list of things/ skills you want to learn. How you would call this list?

Comment: "A list of skills you want to learn" is a good way of describing it.  A professor might write a "syllabus", which is a list of things he plans to teach in a course.  A college may have a "course catalog", which lists and describes the courses taught at the college.  Each listing in the course catalog will have a list of "prerequisites".  A "prerequisite" is something you should know before taking a course.

Comment: Syllabus and prerequisites is too academic. I am looking for a word which is more pleasant-natured. Learn request or Learn wish. Which works best for you?

Comment: Google translate says that "curriculum" means *lehrplan* in German.  Apparently, "*lehr*..." means teaching, and "*lern*..." means learning.  What is the difference between *lernplan* and *lernwunsch*?  https://translate.google.com/#en/de/Curriculum

Comment: I just find "bucket list" inappropriate for this list.

Answer (score 1):

A list of things one desires are "desiderata".  (From the Latin, "desideratum", a desired thing. "Desirderata" is the plural.)

Somewhat unfortunately, the one use of the term most people know is that it is the title of a famous poem.  That association is so strong, it may make this use unsuitable to you.

Answer (score 0):

Goals

Another option is

Things I want to learn

And you know, pleasant is in the ears of the behearer...